# TCPClient Reads Data improperly

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have developed a project which read data from scales.
I can read data that scales send me; however, received datasets aren't convenient. Scale brand is Desis.

Sample output is below.

```
Output:

T,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
T,GS   17.27 g
T,GS   17.27 g
27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
30.89 g

ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
ST,GS   17.27 g
```

Received Data must be ST, GS 17.27 g continuosly.

My Written Codes:

```
public void Connect()
{
            m_tcpClient = new TcpClient();

            m_tcpClient.Connect(m_hostAdress, m_port);

}

public string ReadWithNewLine()
{

            this.Connect();
            m_netWorkStream = m_tcpClient.GetStream();
            m_streamReader = new StreamReader(m_netWorkStream);

            if (m_streamReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_readText = m_streamReader.ReadLine().TrimEnd();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return m_readText + "\r\n";
}
```

Is there any error in code?

Comment: *Something* could be going wrong with `ReadLine`, but you won't know about it because you are hiding errors with the empty `catch` block.

Comment: How are you calling ReadWithNewLine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any error in your code. But i think you are reading one line at a time. if you want to read all lines once then you can use

```
 m_readText = m_streamReader.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd();
```

but if you want to read line by line and get data as you asked in question then i think sender is sending data in that sequence.

Comment: I use Thread.Timer class and I need to read line-by-line, I want to see output of  Hyperterminal. In Hyperterminal, I see data line-by-line. How I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating the TcpClient on each call in `ReadWithNewLine`. If you do that the TcpServer at the other end has to close the old connection and start a new one, negotiating the connection which will lose a couple of bytes each time.

Staying as close as possible to your current design I suggest you try your setup with the following changes:

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        if (m_tcpClient == null)
        {
            m_tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            m_tcpClient.Connect(m_hostAdress, m_port);
            m_netWorkStream = m_tcpClient.GetStream();
            m_streamReader = new StreamReader(m_netWorkStream);
        }
    }

    public string ReadWithNewLine()
    {

        this.Connect();

        try
        {
            m_readText = m_streamReader.ReadLine().TrimEnd();
        } 
        catch (Exception allExceptions)
        {
            m_readText = "Exception:" + allExceptions.Message;
            if (m_tcpClient!=null)
            {
                m_tcpClient.Close();
                m_tcpClient = null; // reset connection
            }
        }
        return m_readText + "\r\n";
    }
```

Notice how I check in the `Connect` method verify there is an instance already of the `TcpClient`. If not, I create one and establish the stream and the reader.

On the first time you call `ReadWithNewLine` it calls `Connect` and setup the connection with your scale. On the next call the Connect will do nothing and re-use the existing reader to get the bytes.

I also slightly changed your exception handling. The least I could do was offer some feedback and reset the TcpClient. You might want to enhance that further to only catch specific exceptions that occur there.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of method you can use to retrieve the response data from the TCPClient. I used flowing code to format the output.

```
        private int TCPTimeOut = 10000;
        private int NetStreamTimeOut = 10000;
        private string ipAddress = "";
        private int port;
        private int intThreadSleep;
        private bool disposed = false;
        private TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        private void GetTCPData()
        {
            tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);
            tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = TCPTimeOut;
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.ReadTimeout = NetStreamTimeOut;

            Byte[] data = new Byte[5210];
            string responseData = String.Empty;

            while (true)
            {
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(intThreadSleep);
                responseData = responseData + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                if (bytes > 10)
                {
                    var table = responseData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                                 StringSplitOptions.None);

                    if (table.Count() > 3)
                    {
                        string line1 = table[0];
                        string line2 = table[1];
                        string line3 = table[2];
                        string line4 = table[3];
                        string line5 = table[4];
                        string line6 = table[5];

                        // SaveData(ipAddress, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6);
                    }
                }
                responseData = String.Empty;
            }

            if (tcpClient != null)
            {
                tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
                tcpClient.Close();
            }

        }
```